# Which Stack Exchange website is for mobiles?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know so many Stack Exchange sites, but I'm a bit confused about where to ask about problems we face in our cell phones. Or any type of any other electronic device.

I am facing so many problems with my phone. So I have so many questions about mobile phones. Please let me know if there is any forum related to mobile phones.

Comment: BTW, Stack Exchange sites aren't forums. They're Q&A sites. This difference is actually quite important, since a lot of the posts typically seen and quite popular on forums are not allowed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please do not post comments asking for upvotes. Their function is to improve the post and make users familiar with Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what phone you have.

- Android phone questions should be asked on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).
- iPhone questions (and questions about other Apple products) should be asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).
- Windows Phone questions (if anyone still has that type of phone) should be asked on the [Windows Phone site](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/).

Questions about computers in general (namely Windows) should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

(Also, none of the above sites take programming questions.)

There is no site for questions about *any* electronic device (which would include things like microwaves), but there are other sites that take questions about *specific* electronic devices, such as [IoT](https://iot.stackexchange.com/).